# Why does "rvm docs generate" use a different directory for output than "gem server"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rdoc

```
rvm use 2@mygemset
rvm docs generate
gem server --help
```

prints:

```
Defaults:
    --port 8808 --dir /home/lsiden/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.1-p353@mygemset --no-daemon
```

But:

```
ls /home/lsiden/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@mygemset/doc
```

is empty.

Where did `rdocs generate` put all the docs it just created?  Shouldn't it match the location where `gem server` sets its docroot?

I also asked the same question on [Github](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2498) but I want to check if someone else already encountered this.

Comment: Why would you expect it to?  That command generates Ruby's core and stdlib documentation.  What does that have to do with a gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docs generate` was initially meant to generate docs for ruby only, not gems, I have extended the command, run this:

```
rvm get head
rvm docs generate-gems
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs.log file:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/share/ri/2.0.0/site...
```

Why would you expect it to? That command generates Ruby's core and stdlib documentation. What does that have to do with a gem?

So, even though you are using a gemset, the `rvm docs` command is more of a Ruby level command.

Comment: Agreed. "gem server" has only gems as its concern. It'd be nice if the docs for both Ruby and gems were available locally via the same interface. Sounds like a good task for the OP.

Comment: The interface, that is already something available. This is what RI (Ruby Interactive) is used for.  The generation of the docs though, when needed, are definitely two fold.  One as the RUby version is available, and then later as each Gem comes in.  Ruby Gems just does it, if you want it to, right in time, at installation.  A lot of people add --no-ri and --no-rdoc in the gemrc file though.  I prefer to have my documentation available locally, and then I only have --no-rdoc.  And I use RI pretty extensively.

Comment: Thank you for your response @vgoff, but since rvm manages the paths to both ruby and a complete gemset, I would have thought that "rvm docs generate" would generate docs for both.  mpapis was very kind nevertheless to provide this following my post to the Github site.  Now I just found out that "gem rdoc --all" accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Indeed.  @mpapis is an authority. :)